# Hyphens Overflowing Line-Clamp

Tags: html, css

How can I prevent word break hyphens from displaying on top of the ellipsis rendered by line-clamp? Here's what happens and what should happen:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 20rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  hyphens: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-word;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -ms-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -moz-line-clamp: 2;
  -ms-line-clamp: 2;
  line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```html
<h1>How it looks</h1>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text" lang="en">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectsetur adiiiiiiipisicing elit. At, laborum!</h2>
</div>
<h1>How it should look:</h1>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text" lang="en">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipis-...</h2>
</div>
```

NOTE: Not all browsers support hyphens property! Here's how it looks in my Firefox: [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? Perhaps on some online code playground?

Comment: What do you want the behavior to be? I'm guessing to keep the hyphen since it's important information for the reader, but maybe show one character less so there is still room for the three dots?

Comment: @Invulner it's best if the SO snippet system is used so the code doesn't get lost in future.

Comment: Which browser is this? It looks like a browser bug to me.

Comment: On my Edge/Windows10 there is no hyphen showing but I do get the 3 dots.

Comment: Your snippet unfortunately just exactly gets the final 'ing' in (on my Edge/FF Windows10) so they correctly show just dots. But if I reduce the container width so the last word shown has to be hyphenated, I still get just the three dots, no hyphen, even on FIrefox. What OS are you on?